# How to create Recurring Appointment Daily, Monthly, Anually in CRM using Plugin or custom workflow?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

I have a requirement, In this i have to create recurring appointment on the basis of daily/weekly/monthly/annually using Plugin or custom workflow in MS Dynamics CRM.

Please suggest me better way to create Recurring Appointment automatically.

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 0):

CRM has Recurring appointments Out-of-the box, use that.